# Setting an entry in a dynamic route template

Tags: routes

I have some routes i want to use like
"/my-url/locationZ"
"/my-url/locationX"

This loads a template /dynamic.twig

In the template dynamic I am trying to get the content from an existing entry like:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries()
       .id('2268')
   %}
```

But the entry is always null.

How can I pull the entry into my dynamic.twig template when the route is used?

Comment: Are you sure the entry exists in your current language?
You should also always query an entry with `.one()` or `.all()` at the end, because not using those is deprecated as of craft 3.

Comment: Doh! Needed .one()

Comment: Can you add that as an official answer?